# mysql explode a field loop through the values and create a new column with the title associated with those values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `users` and `services` and i am try to write a single query that will create a new column `skills`. The values in the column `skills` will be the `service_title` which maps to the `service_id` stored in `user_skills`.

Below are the examples of a the tables used:

```
Table users:
+---------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|   id    |   user_fname  |   user_lname   |   user_skills  |
+---------+---------------+----------------+----------------+ 
|   1     |    kiran      |    bhattarai   |     1,2        |  
|   2     |    sujan      |    bhattarai   |     2,4        |
|   3     |    manorath   |    dad         |     1,2,3,4    |
|   4     |    bhagawoti  |    mom         |     2,3        |
+---------+---------------+----------------+----------------+

Table services:
+-----------------+------------------+
|   service_id    |   service_title  |  
+-----------------+------------------+
|   1             |     cook         |
|   2             |     clean        |
|   3             |     grocessery   |
|   4             |     teach        |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

Currently i am using this query:

```
SELECT users.user_fname,
users.user_lname,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(service_title)
FROM `services`
WHERE `service_id` IN (1,2,3,4)) as skills
FROM users
WHERE
id =3;
```

Result of the above query:

```
+---------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
|   user_fname  |   user_lname   |                 skills                 |
+---------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+ 
|    manorath   |       dad      |     cook,clean,grocessery,teach        |
+---------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Instead of using the `IN (1,2,3,4)` I tried `IN (users.user_skills)` because the values in `user_skills` changes all the time and the result was:

```
+---------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
|   user_fname  |   user_lname   |                 skills                 |
+---------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+ 
|    manorath   |       dad      |                  cook                  |
+---------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Every time a new service is added i have to add that `service_id` in the `IN (1,2,3,4,new service id)` of my query which is not a proper solution. I have already tried using `php` and another query to do solve this, the disadvantage of doing that is it is slowing down the process. How should i solve this problem in a single query.

Comment: See [is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: See [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to JOIN the two tables.

```
SELECT
  u.user_fname,
  u.user_lname,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.service_title) as skills
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN services s
  ON FIND_IN_SET(s.service_id, u.user_skills)
WHERE u.id = 3
```

Note that a JOIN with a `FIND_IN_SET()` condition cannot utilize any index. And that can lead to poor performance.

In general it's a bad idea to store relations in a separated string column. See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

You should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your design and create a separate table for your many-to-many relation. The table would look like

```
Table users_services:
+---------+------------+
| user_id | service_id |
+---------+------------+
|   1     |    1       |
|   1     |    2       |
|   2     |    2       |
|   2     |    4       |
|   3     |    1       |
|   3     |    2       |
|   3     |    3       |
|   3     |    4       |
|   4     |    2       |
|   4     |    3       |
+---------+------------+
```

And the query would be

```
SELECT
  u.user_fname,
  u.user_lname,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.service_title) as skills
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_services us ON us.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN services s ON s.service_id = us.service_id 
WHERE u.id = 3
```